# Program does not contain a suitable 'Main' method for entry point

Tags: c#, program-entry-point, csc

I accidentally deleted the auto generated main entry point of my project. The problem is that I did not realised that and saved the changes and exit de program. Now I have the same error even if I create a new class and a new Main method. The error points to CSC file, but it won' t open anynthin when clicked.
I remember that I somehow oppened the CSC file and deleted all the content inside.
If you have any ideas or suggestion please respond!
Thank you!
[image: This is the error message I get]

Comment: You could just generate another project and compare it or look at one of millions of available examples. Since we can't see the code as it currently is, there's no way to help

Comment: Is the file in your recycle bin now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new Project and if you need the Code of the Program where the Error was copy it and paste it in the new Project

Edit:
If it's an WPF Projects copy the XAML codes